# remove even elements from a list. Showing list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43QDj.png)
please refer to the image.
I want to create a list(say [1,2,3,4,5]). The code checks the divisibility by 2 of every element of the list one by one. if it is divisible by 2, it removes the those elements and returns a list of odd numbers . Please try to keep the code as simple as possible as i am just a beginner....

Comment: Images of code are hard for us to work with.  Please post code and error messages as plain text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = len(l)
new_l = []
for a in range(x):
    if l[a]%2!=0:
        new_l.append(l[a])
new_l
```

Use the above code instead of removing elements from list create a new one.

Comment: Kindly write the reason why you disliked this solution. So that someone can help you with different solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that once you remove the even number from the list, It reduces the length of the list. So in the second iteration of your code, 2 is removed from the list l = [1,2,3,4,5] which modifies the list l to [1,3,4,5], so now, the length of the list is 4 instead of 5. But the for loop, which will run for the values "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" (because of variable x, which is 5), your code produces that error.
To solve this error, you can create a new list and append the even numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier and more Pythonic to build a new list of the odd numbers than it is to modify the original list to remove the even numbers.

If you understand list comprehensions, there's a simple answer.

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [x for x in l if x%2 == 1]
print(l2)
```

You can also do it imperatively:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = []
for x in l:
    if x%2 == 1:
        l2.append(x)
print(l2)
```

Either solution will print `[1, 3, 5]`.

Answer (score -1):

I took a look at the image and couldn't figure out much. Going by your definition

```
l = [1,2,3,4]

for i in l:
    if i % 2 == 0:  # check if i is divisible by 2
         l.remove(i)  # remove the item if the number passes above check.
```

Comment: This will also not work correctly, as it will skip checking some of the values in the list. It won't raise an `IndexError`, but will just give the wrong answer.